# iphone: Large html document into string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am building an HTML file which will later be emailed through my app.  Currently I am creating the html by appending the strings together.  This is a painful process.

Is there another way that I can just put a large block of html into an NSString?  Currently the line breaks in the string are screwing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `NSMutableString` method [`-appendString:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000156-appendString_), or pull the HTML in through a file with the `NSString` method [`-stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJIAAFJ).

Comment: See http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle for examples

Comment: Thanks guys, this, used with stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString worked magic!